# A false conjecture by de Polignac

Tags: elementary-number-theory, conjectures

(This question would be similar to my other on Goldbach's conjecture so I'll change the "rules")

In 1848 de Polignac claimed that "every odd integer is the sum of a prime $p$ and a power of $2$". For example $55=47+2^3=23+2^5.$

Now I have to show that $509$ and $877$ discredit this claim.

What I did is: set $p=509-2^n$ and showed that for every $n$, $p$ is composed (as long as it is nonnegative) checking all the possible values, then I did the same thing for $877$. Fortunately this time I had to check less cases because on the growth of $2^n$ but it still took me a few times.

My question is: how can I prove this without checking case by case and WITHOUT modular arithmetic (which is in the next chap.) ??

EDIT: This question is problem 17 at page 59 (chap.3: the primes and their distribution) of the book "Elementary number theory" by D. M. Burton.

Comment: Do you have reference? I believe that the conjecture is different. It is about the difference between two primes.

Comment: Maybe is just not the same conjecture... @johannesvalks

Comment: Yes, but do you have reference where you have read this conjecture?

Comment: On my book "elementary number theory" by D. M. Burton @johannesvalks

Comment: Reference to a page? Chapter?

Comment: I edit my answer @johannesvalks

Comment: If you still at chap. $3$, you should (maybe) explain in some sentences what you have done in chap. $1,2$ so that we could know what we can use. Now another important thing is that before moving to modular arithmetic which is very important of course, you should know the natural numbers very well, I mean by that you're familiar with them when you see $641$ you can tell in the *blink of an eye* (not sure the correct term) that it's a part of something Big Fermat vs Euler. This is the purpose of this exercise, how would you come with $509$ and $877$ if you don't know the numbers very well ....

Comment: @Elaqqad yes I thought that so but I was afraid that may I miss some strategies around the chapter, btw now I edited my answer so you can find a reference on this problem and its "habitat".

Comment: Well, if you read to the question you know that the claim is wrong, as other examples that $n^2 + n + 41$ is prime that pops up few pages earlier...

Comment: Yes the title of my answer says that to, I'm wondering how to verify that @johannesvalks

Comment: Evidently de Polignac  didn't realize this conjecture was wrong.  If there was a really easy way to see that it's wrong (without explicit calculation) de Polignac would probably have done so.  I suspect he was at least as clever as the average student who reads Burton.

Comment: BTW, your assertion that Burton doesn't cover modular arithmetic until "the end of the book" seemed rather bizarre.  How could any number theory book do that?  But in fact, Chapter 4 is "The theory of congruences".

Comment: And I feel pretty stupid now but still chap.3 is before chap.4 so I didn't fail that hard @RobertIsrael

Comment: For $n\le10^3$ we have $127,~149,~251,~331,~337,~373,~509,~599,~701,~757,~809,~877,$ $905,~907,~959,~977,~997$.